# Как программно изменить url?

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api, history-api

Как в JavaScript изменить url, добавляя параметры, но не перезапуская страницу?

Как использовать History API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл не судьба посетить?
[Первая](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/) и [вторая](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/) ссылка в топе.
Там подробно всё расписано, сюда копипастить бессмысленно.

Comment: Здесь не говорится как из строки mysite.com сделать mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2

Comment: @TwoRS, А разве `history.pushState({}, '', 'mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2')` не работает?

Comment: О. Вот за это спасибо, коллега. Ты какой доктор? )))

Comment: @TwoRS, Я Доктор всяких наук и забавных штуковин :)

Comment: :) Понятно. Я терапевт.Если возникнут вопросы- пиши вконтакте :). И ещё вопрос, если пользователь повыбирал элементы-соответственно изменился урл, затем он переходит на др. страницу. Но вдруг он хочет вернутся обратно- я делаю вариант, что б по get запросу восстановились все выбранные элементы, а есть ли вариант как-то закешировать или в истории сохранить, что б он нажал кнопку назад и вернулся ко все мыбранным элементам?

Comment: Я не тот Доктор, который людей лечит :)  
Людей с иголками я вообще боюсь!  
Обычно такое можно сделать через `LocalStorage` - сохраняй туда и выводи после загрузки.  
Так, например, работает клёвая штука в XenForo: Сохранение введённого текста даже после перезагрузки страницы.  
Иногда случайно перезагружаешь/вырубаешь, а писал много интересного с хорошим оформлением - убить кого-нибудь хочется :)